# webpack, jquery and dynamic form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, jquery-select2

I'm using webpack and jQuery in my symfony project.
I configured webpack and jquery as follows :

```js
// webpack.common.js
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/default/index.js",
    commons: "./src/default/js/app.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    clean: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        test: /datatables\.net.*/, 
        use: [{
          loader: 'imports-loader',
          options: {
            additionalCode: 
              "var define = false;"
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve("jquery"),
        loader: "expose-loader",
        options: {
          exposes: ["$", "jQuery"],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [{
          // inject CSS to page
          loader: 'style-loader'
        }, {
          // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
          loader: 'css-loader'
        }, {
          // Run postcss actions
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            // `postcssOptions` is needed for postcss 8.x;
            // if you use postcss 7.x skip the key
            postcssOptions: {
              // postcss plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
              plugins: function () {
                return [
                  require('autoprefixer')
                ];
              }
            }
          }
        }, {
          // compiles Sass to CSS
          loader: 'sass-loader'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    })
  ]
}
```

```js
// index.js
import 'bootstrap';

import './scss/app.scss';

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands';

require('select2');

require('jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker');
require('jquery-ui/ui/i18n/datepicker-fr.js')

import 'datatables.net';
import dt from 'datatables.net-bs5';

import 'datatables.net-bs5/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css';

dt(window, $);
```

My project use an old jQuery Plugin I made for simplify the use of select2 in my project called `select2Helper`.

```
if ( "undefined" !== typeof jQuery ) {
    (function($, window, document) {
        $(function() {
            $.select2Helper = function(element, options) {
                // Do stuff
            }
            
            // Add the plugin to jQuery functions (jQuery.fn object)
            $.fn.select2Helper = function(options) {
                
                // Iteration through the DOM elements we are attaching the plugin
                return this.each(function(){
                    // If the plugin has not already been attached to the element
                    if (undefined == $(this).data('select2Helper')) {
                        
                        // Create new instance of the plugin with current DOM element and user-provided options
                        var plugin = new $.select2Helper(this, options);
                        
                        // In the jQuery version of the element,
                        // store a reference to the plugin object
                        // for access to the plugin from outside like 
                        // element.data('select2Helper').foo(), etc.
                        $(this).data('select2Helper', plugin);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

This plugin was written based on the official jQuery plugin "how to write plugin" documentation.

I load this plugin outside of webpack (old style) so I need to access `$` outside of webpack. This scripts use Select2 plugin for initialize autocompletion on select form element.

**So far so good.**

I'm facing a problem when I want to add dynamically a field that use jQuery select2 Plugin (after page loading).

When I do this (adding new select2 field in my form) and initialize select field with select2 :

```js
if ( "undefined" !== typeof jQuery ) {
    (function($, window, document) {
        $(function() {
           $('.select2-element').select2Helper(config);
        });
    }(window.jQuery, window, document));
}
```

The result is : "Select2Helper is not defined."

### First test

When I do :

```js
if ( "undefined" !== typeof jQuery ) {
    (function($, window, document) {
        $(function() {
           console.info($.fn);
        });
    }(window.jQuery, window, document));
}
```

The result shows me that select2Helper is in the `$.fn` list (`$.fn.select2Helper`). But the same code invoked after page loading show me that select2Helper is not in the list.

### Second test

When I do on page loading :

```js
if ( "undefined" !== typeof jQuery ) {
    (function($, window, document) {
        $(function() {
           console.info(jQuery);
           console.info($);
        });
    }(window.jQuery, window, document));
}
```

The return of `console.info(jQuery)` is not the same as `console.info($)`. In the first I don't have select2Helper in `jQuery.fn` but it is present in `$.fn` .

I identified that the `$` object used after page loading is same as `jQuery` object above not `$` object above.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

My error is not from my jQuery plugin select2Helper or jQuery. Is from a lack of knowledge of webpack and its configuration.

When I Wrote :

```js
// webpack.common.js
const path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "./src/default/index.js",
    commons: "./src/default/js/app.js"
  },
  // ...
}
```

I defined two entries. For each entries, webpack build two versions of jQuery. My original idea was to integrate a little extra script on top of the rest with some javascript stuff in it. But I realized that it was building a commons.bundle.js with app.js file in it with everything (jQuery, datatable, etc.).

I end up with a file `main.bundle.js` with jQuery (and other stuffs) in it AND a `commons.bundle.js` also with jQuery but not the same one, hence the two versions of jQuery.

I copy / paste my little javascript stuffs from app.js directly in index.js and everything work fine now.